# When using NInject in ASP.Net MVC application then give exception on when instantiating the kernel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

When I try to add the NInject using the Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager, when I run the MVC project specially the method `CreateKernel()` runs the following error occurrs:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
> Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Exception :"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add binding [redirects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ash1ksb(v=vs.110).aspx) for the assembly:

```
<runtime>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```